# How to index a high dimensional array with 2 index arrays

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a (2 x 1 x 2 x 2 x 2) dimensional array:

```
array([[[[[ 7.,  9.],
          [10., 11.]],

         [[19., 18.],
          [20., 16.]]]],



       [[[[24.,  5.],
          [ 6., 10.]],

         [[18., 11.],
          [45., 12.]]]]])
```

The last two dimensions are H (height) and W (width) respectively. Now I have two separate arrays with indexing along H and W:

```
idx2=np.array([1, 1, 0, 1]) # index along H
idx3=np.array([1, 0, 0, 0]) # index along W
```

Therefore, in terms of last two dimensions, I'd like to extract the (1,1)th element from `[[ 7.,9.],[10.,11.]]`, that is, 11; and the (1,0)th element from `[[19.,18.],[20.,16.]]`, that is 20, and so on. The final result should be a **(2 x 1 x 2) array**:

```
array([[[11., 20.]],

       [[24., 45.]]])
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why is the third number `24.` and not `10.`?

Comment: because it's the (0,0)th from `[[24.,  5.], [ 6., 10.]]` that is 24. Similarly, the last one 45 is the (1,0)th of [[18., 11.], [45., 12.]]

Comment: I assume this is array is produced with `as_strided` as in your previous question.  If so the array is a `view`.  But most formas of advanced indexing will create a copy, and 'break' the link to the original.  The same applies to any reshape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible way of solving this using a combination of `np.ravel_multi_index` and `np.take_along_axis`.

---

You could unravel the indexes on the last two dimensions and use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) on this flattened spatial dimension `h x w` axis:

```
>>> flat_idx = (idx2*x.shape[-1]+idx3).reshape(*x.shape[:-2], 1)
>>> flat_idx 
array([[[[3],
         [2]]],


       [[[0],
         [2]]]])
```

Alternatively, you can choose to use the builtin [`np.ravel_multi_index`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html#numpy.ravel_multi_index), but it is slightly longer:

```
>>> flat_idx = np.ravel_multi_index((idx2, idx3), x.shape[-2:]).reshape(*x.shape[:-2], 1)
```

Then flatten the last two dimensions of `x` and gather the indices:

```
>>> res = np.take_along_axis(x.reshape(*x.shape[:-2], -1), flat_idx, -1)
>>> res
array([[[[11.],
         [20.]]],


       [[[24.],
         [45.]]]])
```

At this point a reshape will be necessary:

```
>>> res.reshape(*x.shape[0:-2])
array([[[11., 20.]],

       [[24., 45.]]])
```

---

If you infer the shapes, with `idx2` and `idx3` this comes down to:

```
>>> flat_idx = (idx2*2+idx3).reshape(2, 1, 2, 1)
>>> res = np.take_along_axis(x.reshape(2, 1, 2, 4), flat_idx, -1)
>>> res.reshape((2, 1, 2))
```

---

The above method can be used to handle a more general case with `idx2`, `idx3`, `idx4`, ...

Comment: This is brilliant! Thanks Ivan!

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ivan. BTW, do you see a way to use advanced indexing in this case? something like x[i,j,k,idx2,idx3]-->final (2x1x2) dim array?

Comment: What do you mean by advanced indexing here?

Comment: like https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html? I don't know, just wondering if it is possible to use x[some indices] to get the final result. I've tried but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Not sure, you seem to refer to a different method, here we don't rely on indexing but instead use unraveled indices on a flattened axis.

Comment: no worries! as long as it works! thanks Ivan

Answer (score 0):

Check out [numpy indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html) :

```
idx0=np.array([0,0,1,1])
idx1=np.array([0,1,0,1])
array[idx0,0,idx1,idx2,idx3]
```

Another more hacky way: (I've named the array a in my code)

```
np.diag(a[:,:,:,idx2,idx3].reshape((4,-1)))
```

You'd have to replace 4 by the product of the other dimensions in the general case.

Comment: For more complicated indexes you'd have to use https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html

Comment: thanks for your answer, what is idx0 and idx1?

Comment: Hi `ix_` creates a grid right? so if I use (4x1) `idx2` and (1x4) `idx3` then there'll be 4x4=16 numbers retrieved

Comment: Ideally you could just use array[:,:,:,idx2,idx3] however basic slicing + advanced indexing doesn't work that way. So either you do as @ivan with take along or you advanced integer index. In order to advanced index, you need integer indexes for the first 3 axes. Because this was a simple case, i could simply write idx0 and idx1 by hand. However for bigger arrays, creating idx 0 and idx 1 could be done with ix_. You really should read the advanced integer indexing docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 2x1x2x2x2 dimensional array, `array_name`.

```
import numpy as np
array_name = np.array([[[[[ 7.,  9.],
                          [10., 11.]],
                         [[19., 18.],
                          [20., 16.]]]],
                       [[[[24.,  5.],
                          [ 6., 10.]],
                         [[18., 11.],
                          [45., 12.]]]]])
```

`array_name[0]` and `array_name[1]` are both 1x2x2x2 dimensional arrays.

```
array_name[0].shape # (1, 2, 2, 2)
```

`array_name[0][0]` is a 2x2x2 dimensional array.

```
array_name[0][0].shape # (2, 2, 2)
```

`array_name[0][0][0]` is a 2x2 dimensional array.

```
array_name[0][0][0].shape # (2, 2)
```

`array_name[0][0][0][0]` is a 2 dimensional array.

```
array_name[0][0][0][0].shape # (2,)
```

For the array given in the question:

```
array_name[0][0][0][1][1] # 11.
array_name[0][0][1][1][0] # 20.
array_name[1][0][0][0][0] # 24.
array_name[1][0][1][1][0] # 45.
```

This method is incredibly verbose so instead you can use advanced indexing.

```
idx_0 = [0,0,1,1]
idx_2 = [0,1,0,1]
idx_3 = [1,1,0,1]
idx_4 = [1,0,0,0]
```

The values in each of the `idx_X` arrays are taken from the array indexes in the verbose code above and are used to create a single array of 4 elements like so.

```
array_name[idx_0, 0, idx_2, idx_3, idx_4]
# array([11., 20., 24., 45.])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your output is not the correct shape I want (2x1x2). actually you can simply obtain those leading indices idx_0, idx_1..., using `i,j,k=np.indices(array_name.shape[:-2])`, so `array_name[i.flatten(),j.flatten(),k,flatten(),idx2,idx3]` will give `[11,20,24,45]`